# Cheese will not start in 12.04

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, cheese

I start Cheese on my 12.04 installation. I have used it before in my previous installations but since I upgraded to 12.04, no joy!  I have a GeForce GT-520 video card with the "recommended" additional proprietary drivers installed and activated.

I tried to run Cheese from the terminal and got the following errors:

dozens of these errors:

```
(cheese:5467): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gnome-applications-light.css:42:23: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.
```

about a dozen of these errors:

```
(cheese:5467): Gtk-WARNING **: Attempting to add a widget with type GtkImage to a 
GtkToggleButton, but as a GtkBin subclass a GtkToggleButton can only contain one widget
at a time; it already contains a widget of type GtkLabel
```

only one of these errors:

```
(cheese:5467): CRITICAL **: cheese_camera_device_get_uuid: assertion 
CHEESE_IS_CAMERA_DEVICE (device)' failed
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Answer (score 0):

Probe with this

Alt + F2 >> gstreamer properties >> section video and probe your dispositive (check correct device, is possible have 2 or + in your /dev/video)... if you webcam working, is problem identifier device for cheese, change en dconf apps >> cheese >> camera -- for /dev/video #Number for you webcam.

Comment: Hi, welcome to AskUbuntu! Please elaborate / clarify your answer to make it more useful. For example, explain how to probe, what the exact command is for gstreamer properties, etc.